# Fluoride stack support for VS commands

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, android-source

I'm working in an embedded systems that runs Android 8.0 with kernel version 4.4. The HW is a custom board based on Jacinto 8 from TI.

Actually, we're trying to integrate a new BT controller, that will replace the existing one. This new chip is CC2564C from TI.

Unfortunately I couldn't find much documentation about the stack, and the interrelationship between its different layers.

The problem I am experiencing is that at the time of receiving a hfp call, I need to send a vendor specific command to the CC2564C in order to change a configuration, and I am not sure from which part of the stack I should send that command, since for the controller we used before This additional command was not necessary.

Is there anyone with experience in this type of tasks who can guide me?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to add a separated app that run in background and send that vs command, but that approach was not useful, because if I register my own callbacks for controller's response, I'm overwriting callbacks from hci_layer_android, and some related problems arises